# Draw circle when touched and when touch is removed in a custom view

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw to different circles when the user touches the screen and when the touch is removed.
I am somewhat successfull but the start touch circle disapperas when the "ACTION_UP" event circle is drawn.

Not sure What is going wrong.
My OnDraw and OnTouch functions are below

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //drawing lines
        //lines
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
        //circles
        //canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
    }


public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    // return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  //  points.add(point);
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        point.x = (int)event.getX();
        point.y = (int)event.getY();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        point.x = (int)event.getX();
        point.y = (int)event.getY();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to draw multiple circles when the user touches the screen and touch removed, you need to use a `List` of circles. you can have an `ExampleCircle` class where it have an x,y and color field.

```
public class ExampleCircle{

int x,y;
Color color;
//setters and getters

}
```

//onTouch
//assuming you already have a List object (List circleList=new ArrayList(); )

```
ExampleCircle newCircle=new ExampleCircle();
 switch(event.getAction()){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
    newCircle.setX((int)event.getX());
    newCircle.setY((int)event.getY()) ;
    newCircle.setColor(paint.setColor(Color.BLACK));
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    newCircle.setX((int)event.getX());
    newCircle.setY((int)event.getY()) ;
    newCircle.setColor(paint.setColor(Color.BLACK));
    break;
}

circleList.add(newCircle);
invalidate();
return true;
```

//on draw method

replace

```
    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
```

with

```
for(int i=0;i<circleList.size();i++){
   ExampleCircle currentCircle=circleList.get(i);

        canvas.drawCircle(currentCircle.getX(), currentCircle.getY(), 5, paint or currentCircle.getColor());

}
```

Comment: Okay,Thanks , so if i understand correctly basically i need to add all the point to a list and the draw the entire canvas again.
Will this not effect the performace when i have many Circles ??

Comment: somehow it will.because single circle is different from multiple circle right?